# Use keras mobilenet model

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to use Keras' MobileNet to do image classification. My input shape is `(64, 64, 3)` and there are two classes in my dataset. I don't want to use the trained weights.

Here is my code.

```
model = MobileNet(weights=None, include_top=True, input_shape=(64, 64, 3), classes=2)
```

My questions is, `include_top` should be `True` or `False`?
Since the official said that,

**input_shape:** optional shape tuple, only to be specified if include_top is False

**include_top:** whether to include the fully-connected layer at the top of the network.

I would like to do image classification, so I think my last layer should be full-connected. Is it correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass an input shape of (64,64,3) then you need to

```
include_top=False
```

Yes you will need fully-connected layer at the end.You will have to build your own top to the network. Your model will be something like this

```
base_model= MobileNet(weights=None, include_top=False, input_shape=(64, 64, 3))
x=base_model.output
x=Flatten()(x)
x=Dense(...)(x)
.
.
# Softmax layer for classification
predictions=Dense(2,activation='softmax')
model=(x=base_model.input,output=predictions)
```

I do not know why we need to remove the fully connected layers to change the input_shape, but I think the above solution will work

**Edit:**

> Why should we set include_top to False if input_shape is different?

Because it changes the input size to the fully connected layers at the end.
Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50054938/why-do-we-need-to-include-top-false-if-we-need-to-change-the-input-shape) answer for further explanation

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know I can build the dense layer by myself as you said. But I just want to make sure if the code I wrote above is correct. Actually I tried and it worked. Why should we set include_top to False if input_shape is different?

Comment: @TeresaK. Yeah your code is correct. Refer to the edit